# Ajax Login not returning results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, authentication

I've created a login box in a modal, but I'm not able to get the results back for some reason. I'm very new to javascript, so I'm guessing it's something obvious!

```
$('#login').click(function()
        {

          $("#buttons").hide();
          $("#progress").show();
          var email=$("#email").val();
          var password=$("#password").val();
          var dataString = 'email='+email+'&UserPW='+password;
          if($.trim(email).length>0 && $.trim(password).length>0)
          {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/php/ajaxLogin.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){
              $("#buttons").hide();
              $("#progress").show();
            ;},
            success: function(data){
              if(data)
              {
                console.log(data);
                if (data = "client/staff")
                {
                  $("#clientStaffToggleButtons").show();
                }
                if (data = "staff")
                {
                  $("body").load("staff/dashboard.php").hide().fadeIn(1500).delay(6000);
                }
                if (data = "client")
                {
                  $("body").load("myevent/dashboard.php").hide().fadeIn(1500).delay(6000);
                }
                if (data = "noEmail")
                {
                    $("#buttons").show();
                    $("#progress").hide();
                    //Shake animation effect.
                    $('#formLogin').shake();
                    $("#signInSubmit").val('Sign In')
                    $("#error").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> Invalid username and password. ");
                }
                if (data == "noPW")
                {
                    $("#buttons").show();
                    $("#progress").hide();
                    //Shake animation effect.
                    $('#formLogin').shake();
                    $("#signInSubmit").val('Sign In')
                    $("#error").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> Invalid username and password. ");
                }
              }
            }
          });

          }
          return false;
```

Any ideas on what may be wrong?

Much thanks!! :D

***EDIT***
Just to clarify, I'm getting the functions back (through console log) but they don't seem to be actually doing anything in the if-then statements, for example:

if (data = "client/staff")

doesn't seem to be doing anything, even if data returned was "client/staff"

to test it out go to fiestausa.com and hit login on the top-right

Comment: Add an error handler to the Ajax call

Comment: Check the console for errors, and look at the network debugger tab (Chrome) to see if a request to "includes/php/ajaxLogin.php" is ever made.

Comment: Firstly as @epascarello said, add error handler `error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)` and secondly, `beforeSend` ending seems to have an additional unwanted semicolon

Comment: So, I'm getting the results back, but they don't seem to be doing anything...

Comment: I may be a little rusty haha but when doing comparisons, do you not need "==" or "===" Your assigning the value to data.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the assignment operator (`=`), instead of the comparison operator (`===` or `==` if you don't care about the type), so stuff like this:

```
if (data = "client/staff")
```

should become this:

```
if (data === "client/staff")
```

---

The assignment operator returns the assignment value, so in your case the if line from above equals to:

```
data = "client/staff";
if ("client/staff")
```

and that evaluates to true since a non-empty strings are truthy.

Comment: I've tried changing it to == and === and it still doesn't work :( It returns the variable to console but it doesn't perform the action

Comment: Can you paste exactly what the `data` is in one example?

Comment: the console shows client/staff when I try to log in, and incorrect if I type the wrong password

Comment: Well, if you're absolutely sure it returns `client/staff`, it should trigger this: `$("#clientStaffToggleButtons").show();`  Why don't you add another console log just above that line to make sure the code gets there?

Comment: That means your ifs are working fine (btw. for optimization purposes you might want to use else/ifs instead of multiple ifs). Just tested, `$("#clientStaffToggleButtons")` does not exist... that's the problem.

Comment: The actual code is $("#clientStaffButtons").show(); but I added Toggle so people would know what it did

Comment: And good idea, I'll change it to else/ifs! :D Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: Looks like it all works then! :) You're welcome, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86734/discussion-between-timothy-richard-elliott-and-shomz).

Comment: I've even tried this and it doesn't work:
console.log(data);

                var result = data;

                  console.log(result);
                if (result == "client/staff")
                {
                  $("#clientStaffButtons").show();
                }
                if (data == "staff")
                {
                  $("body").load("staff/dashboard.php").hide().fadeIn(1500).delay(6000);
                }

Comment: Hmm, are you sure you don't have a space or something in your return string? It has to be an EXACT match.

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect use of comparisons:

```
$('#login').click(function(e)
        {
          e.preventDefault();

          $("#buttons").hide();
          $("#progress").show();
          var email=$("#email").val();
          var password=$("#password").val();
          var dataString = 'email='+email+'&UserPW='+password;
          if($.trim(email).length>0 && $.trim(password).length>0)
          {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/php/ajaxLogin.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){
              $("#buttons").hide();
              $("#progress").show();
            ;},
            success: function(data){
              if(data.d)
              {
                console.log(data.d);
                if (data.d == "client/staff")
                {
                  $("#clientStaffToggleButtons").show();
                }
                if (data.d == "staff")
                {
                  $("body").load("staff/dashboard.php").hide().fadeIn(1500).delay(6000);
                }
                if (data.d == "client")
                {
                  $("body").load("myevent/dashboard.php").hide().fadeIn(1500).delay(6000);
                }
                if (data.d == "noEmail")
                {
                    $("#buttons").show();
                    $("#progress").hide();
                    //Shake animation effect.
                    $('#formLogin').shake();
                    $("#signInSubmit").val('Sign In')
                    $("#error").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> Invalid username and password. ");
                }
                if (data.d == "noPW")
                {
                    $("#buttons").show();
                    $("#progress").hide();
                    //Shake animation effect.
                    $('#formLogin').shake();
                    $("#signInSubmit").val('Sign In')
                    $("#error").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> Invalid username and password. ");
                }
              }
            }
          });
         }
```

"return false" is now deprecated.

Comment: What does adding ".d" to data do?

Comment: Rather than trying to explain and make a mess of it haha. An article that explains a lot better: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/